# Python: Finding a substring in a string, but returning True or False instead of the index position

Tags: python, string, find, boolean

I need to check if a substring is part of a specific string. The substring is 'AAA' and if it is found in the given string, it must return True. If it isn't in the string, it must return False

```
def isResistent(virus):
    gen = "AAA"
    if gen in virus:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAAGCT')
```

It returns True or False, but besides True or False it first gives the index number or something. When I run the program several times it returns:

**Output:**

```
2
True

1
True

2
True

4
True

0 
True
```

Is it possible to only print True or False?

Comment: This code does not behave as you claim.

Comment: You print 1 or 2 or so somewhere else.

Comment: Why `print("True")` and not `return True`?

Comment: When I run it, it prints a number, and then it prints True....Just as claimed above

Comment: @RoadRunner I tried return True, but if I do so, it only prints the number

Comment: it then means somewhere outside this function, some other function has captured your boolean values and print 1 given True, print 2 given False.

Comment: I'm sorry, I imported a file of mine in the top (that code isn't included) and because of that it returned this number. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Can you include the code for that file import? It's very hard to resolve an error / behaviour without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: I'm sorry for the problem, I've spotted the problem and fixed it. It's working now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function should just `return 'AAA' in virus`.

```
def isResistent(virus):
    return 'AAA' in virus

>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAAGCT')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine when you use `return` instead:

```
def isResistent(virus):
    gen = "AAA"
    if gen in virus:
        return True
    else:
        return False

>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAAGCT')
True
>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGGCTGCT')
False
```

I would also include `gen` as a function parameter, so you can test other sub strings other than `"AAA"` in the future:

```
def isResistent(virus, gen):
    return gen in virus

>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAAGCT', 'AAA')
True
>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGGCTGCT', 'AAA')
False
>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAAGCT', 'AGC')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to account for lowercase uses like `aaa` `AAa` `Aaa` (etc)
which I have found useful if pulling out specific words from a sentence, based on [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)'s response:

```
def isResistent(virus):
    return 'aaa' in virus.lower()

>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAaAGCT')
True
>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAAGCT')
True
```

or [RoadRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238915/roadrunner)'s:

```
def isResistent(virus, gen):
    return gen.lower() in virus.lower()

>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGAAaGCT', 'AAA')
True
>>> isResistent('GCAAGCTGGTCGTGGCTGCT', 'AAA')
False
>>> isResistent('GCAagcTGGTCGTGAAAGCT', 'AGC')
True
```

Example:

```
def findWord(string, word):
    """
    Outputs true or false if word is found, can be upper or lower. 
    Does NOT account for punctuation.
    """
    return word.lower() in string.lower()
    
>>> findWord('Is there a WORD here?', 'Word')
True
```